Proof that the Hamming distance is a metric
If $x$, $y$,  are words of length $n$ in a code $C$, $x=x_1 \cdots x_n$, $y=y_1 \cdots y_n$ we define
$$d(x, y)= d(x_1, y_1) + \cdots + d(x_n, y_n)$$
from where
$$\quad d(x_i, y_i)=0 \text{ if } x_i=y_i \quad \text{ and } d(x_i, y_i)=1 \text{ if } x_i \neq y_i$$
So let's review the characteristics that a metric meets.

My idea to proof for non-negativity is to separate the summands, on the one hand those that cancel out and on the other hand those that remain distinct, i.e.

$$d(x, y)=\sum_{i=1, x_i \neq y_i}^q d(x_i, y_i)+ \sum_{i=1, x_i = y_i}^p d(x_i, y_i)= (1+ \cdots +1) + 0 \geq 0$$

Lets check out that $d(x, y)=0$ iff $x=y$
If
$\sum_{i=1}^n d(x_i, y_i)=0$, as $d(x_i, y_i) \geq 0$, $d(x_i, y_i)=0$, thus $x_i=y_i$ and $x=y$
The converse is similar

3)For the symmetry I did something similar to side 1), split the sum in two and commute the resulting summands.
Now, for the triangular inequality I have tried to see it by cases, but I don't see it at all clear, any help? I appreciate it

This is correct, this question is a duplicate and thus should be closed. I deleted my answer because of this.

@Mike Given your support, I no longer hesitated using my dupehammer on this occasion.

@Mike You say that the proof of 1, 2 and 3 is correct?, that it would only remain to see the triangular inequality, really your answer would have been very useful, because in the link posted to the repeated question, the answer is not quite similar to my way of approaching the problem.
